# How will GNOME 3.8 Classic Mode composite should I use it with Compiz?

Tags: compiz, gnome-classic, compositing

Definitely wanna try the new Classic Mode in GNOME 3.8, as it looks really nice from the screenshots, however I'm a bit curious how well it'll composite when coupled with some compositing manager, like for example, Compiz, as I bet you could do some pretty sweet stuff with a compositing manager in it.

Any of you try to composite GNOME 3.8 Fallback before?

Answer (score 0):

fallback is removed from 3.8 An alternative called flashback is in.

How well it plays with compiz I do not know; but on archlinux it seems to not work so I just use a custom gnome-session for compiz instead of the gnome-flashback thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Fallback now there is Flashback. It perfectly works with Compiz, with all settings and effects. At least at 13.10.